# Ошибка при развёртывании с maven на tomcat

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat, maven

При развёртывании приложения используя maven, получаю след ошибку..

- В чем может быть дело ?

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>CouponSystem</groupId>
  <artifactId>CouponSystem</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
<sourceDirectory>src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>src\main\test</testSourceDirectory>
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
       <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
       <server>CouponSystem</server>
       <username>admin</username>
       <password>admin</password>
       <path>http://localhost:8080/CouponSystem</path>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
  <repository>
     <id>companyname.lib1</id>
     <url>http://download.companyname.org/maven2/lib1</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
     <id>companyname.lib2</id>
     <url>http://download.companyname.org/maven2/lib2</url>
  </repository>
   </repositories>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>connector</groupId>
 <artifactId>mysql-connector</artifactId>
 <version>02</version>
 </dependency>
  <dependency>
<groupId>couponproject</groupId>
<artifactId>coupon-project</artifactId>
<version>01</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
<version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
<version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
<groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
<artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>5.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
<groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
<version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

> > [INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080
> >     Uploading: http://localhost:8080/html/deploy?path=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A808
> >     [INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
> >     [INFO] Retrying request
> >     Uploading: http://localhost:8080/html/deploy?path=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080
> >     [INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
> >     [INFO] Retrying request
> >     Uploading: http://localhost:8080/html/deploy?path=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080
> >     [INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
> >     [INFO] Retrying request
> >     Uploading: http://localhost:8080/html/deploy?path=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080
> >
> > [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) on project CouponSystem: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection reset -> [Help 1]

Структура проекта: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробувал без исплользования maven, всёравно получил ошибку при запросе на ресурс. Ошибка 404! Не смотря на то что моя веб апликация "running" на самом томкат.

Comment: покажите структуру проекта.

Comment: Структура проекта.